# Where source file that is related to WebGL is placed in Chronium?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I'm engaging in the project to use WebGL. I think if I could see the source of Chronium related to WebGL, It would be very helpful to solve any bugs.

Thus, I tried to find sources in Chronium project repository(https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master).
But, I could not find any files related to WebGL so far. Does anyone knows where is the source code related to WebGL?

Comment: Did you try [grepping the code for any of the API calls](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=framebufferRenderbuffer&sq=package:chromium&type=cs)?

Comment: I noticed that these code was hosted in Google Code, and Google Code has feature to search in source files.
 It must be helpful for this purpose.
I thought these source was only hosted in chronium.googlesource.com.
Thank you, your comment was really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a better link to browse the source of Chromium:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/

WebGL related classes are in "src/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/webgl/", for example here is "WebGLRenderingContext.h":
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/webgl/WebGLRenderingContext.h&q=webglrender&sq=package:chromium&l=1

Chrome is now using the "Blink" rendering engine, related WebGL classes are for example here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/out/Debug/gen/blink/bindings/modules/v8/V8WebGLRenderingContext.h&sq=package:chromium&q=v8webglren&l=1

For more info about Blink:
http://www.chromium.org/blink

I also recommend reading Brandon Jones' blog post about Blink and WebGL:
http://blog.tojicode.com/2013/05/how-blink-has-affected-webgl.html